# Do not include record unless it is the only record that exists for an item in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a transaction table that if something happens to a record, a flag is applied.  So for example, take a pen.  If someone has counted how many pens we have it creates a record with item = 'pen', a date = '1/1/15', and a flag = c that it was counted.  Then perhaps, someone else will take a pen, it inserts a record item = 'pen', a date = '2/15/15' and flag = 't'.  Then we need pens, so someone ordered pens, it inserts a record item = 'pen', date = '3/12/15' and flag = 'o'.

So now I want to know if any transactions happened on pens but I don't care if it has been counted, easy enough.  select * from table where flag <> 'c'.  Here's where I'm stuck.  We have pencils, where the only transaction that exists are the counted transactions.

I want a query to show me where transactions other then counted have happened unless the only transaction that exists is its been counted.

This is what I would like the output to be:

```
Pen      2/15/15   T
Pen      3/12/15   O
Pencil   1/1/15    C
```

Comment: Please clarify: What does "a flag is applied" mean? When a transaction happens, does your program INSERT a new row to the table, or does it update the existing row?

Comment: Sorry about that, it inserts a new record into the table.  So for the pens, 3 records would exist.  But for the pencil only one does.

Comment: What columns are in the table? What columns do you want in the result set?

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more clear, quite hard to understand how it is written now.

Comment: Columns are Item, Flag and Date.  I want all 3 columns.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question and provided what I would like the output to look like.  I hope this helps.  Using SQL Server.

Comment: Can there be more than one `C` record for the same type - e.g. on different dates? The title implies singular but " counted transactions" implies plural.

Answer (score 0):

You need one or more rows per distinct item / date combination.

One row per distinct combination:

```
       SELECT DISTINCT Item, `Date`
         FROM table
```

One row for each non-`'c'` transaction:

```
         SELECT Item, [Date], Flag
           FROM table
          WHERE Flag <> 'c'
```

Now, use a LEFT JOIN to merge these two tables together.

```
SELECT a.Item, a.`Date`, b.Flag
  FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT Item, [Date]
         FROM table
        ) a
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT Item, [Date], Flag
           FROM table
          WHERE Flag <> 'c'
      ) b ON a.Item = b.Item and a.[Date] = b.[Date]
```

This should give you NULLs in the third result set column where there's nothing but a `c` record.

Or if you want `c` in the `c`-only records:

```
  SELECT a.Item, a.[Date], ISNULL(b.Flag,a.Flag) Flag
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could do

```
WITH s
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(CASE
                        WHEN [Flag] <> 'C' THEN 1
                      END)
                  OVER(
                    PARTITION BY [Item] ) AS NonC_Count
         FROM   Stationery)
SELECT Item,
       Date,
       Flag
FROM   s
WHERE  [Flag] <> 'C'
        OR NonC_Count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a Group Count:

```
select item, date, flag
from
 (
   select item, date, flag,
      count(*) over (partition by item) as cnt
   from tab
 ) as dt
where (cnt > 1 and flag <> 'C')
   or (cnt = 1 and flag  = 'C')
```

Comment: @MartinSmith: Correct. Your query does the logic the right way :-)

Comment: I deleted that comment as the question is ambiguous and switches between singular and plural.